# Unable to start embedded Tomcat due to "Injection of autowired dependencies failed"

Tags: spring, tomcat, tomcat7

I am new to Java and currently responsible for managing a new application. I am trying to start the application and its failing with the below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:133)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:531)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:687)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:967)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:956)
        at com.thinkbiganalytics.controller.Application.main(Application.java:53)
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:98)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.<init>(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:75)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:378)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:155)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:157)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:130)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.setFilterChainProxySecurityConfigurer(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor,java.util.List) throws java.lang.Exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'formBasedWebSecurityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider com.thinkbiganalytics.auth.FormBasedWebSecurityConfiguration.authenticationProvider; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authenticationProvider': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.thinkbiganalytics.auth.AuthenticationService com.thinkbiganalytics.auth.AuthServiceAuthenticationProvider.authenticationService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authenticationService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.thinkbiganalytics.datalake.podium.restclient.PodiumRestClient com.thinkbiganalytics.datalake.podium.auth.PodiumAuthenticationService.podiumRestClient; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'podiumRestClientImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private boolean com.thinkbiganalytics.datalake.podium.restclient.PodiumRestClientImpl.useHttps; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'boolean'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid boolean value [${podium.useHttps}]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## TL;DR: Read the error Spring gives you.

Lets take the error and systematically go through it:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
            at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:133)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:531)
            at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:687)
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:967)
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:956)
            at com.thinkbiganalytics.controller.Application.main(Application.java:53)
    Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
            at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:98)
            at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.<init>(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:75)
            at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:378)
            at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:155)
            at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:157)
            at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:130)
            ... 7 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.setFilterChainProxySecurityConfigurer(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor,java.util.List) throws java.lang.Exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'formBasedWebSecurityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider com.thinkbiganalytics.auth.FormBasedWebSecurityConfiguration.authenticationProvider; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authenticationProvider': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.thinkbiganalytics.auth.AuthenticationService com.thinkbiganalytics.auth.AuthServiceAuthenticationProvider.authenticationService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authenticationService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.thinkbiganalytics.datalake.podium.restclient.PodiumRestClient com.thinkbiganalytics.datalake.podium.auth.PodiumAuthenticationService.podiumRestClient; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'podiumRestClientImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private boolean com.thinkbiganalytics.datalake.podium.restclient.PodiumRestClientImpl.useHttps; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'boolean'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid boolean value [${podium.useHttps}]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
```

First we have `Exception in thread "main"` - this doesn't tell us anything except that the status has blown up due to "Unable to start embedded container".

Okay, what caused that, lets go to the next level:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
```

Okay, not much more there. Lets go to the next level:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed
```

Okay, now we're getting somewhere - we couldn't create a `WebSecurityConfiguration` due to an autowiring problem, but what is that problem?

```
Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.setFilterChainProxySecurityConfigurer(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor,java.util.List)
```

Ah, okay, Spring couldn't autowire that method, why not?

```
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'formBasedWebSecurityConfiguration'
```

Ah, okay - so it couldn't autowire that method method it couldn't create a `formBasedWebSecurityConfiguration`. Why not?

```
Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider
```

Ah, no `AuthenticationProvider`. Why not?

```
Could not autowire field: private com.thinkbiganalytics.auth.AuthenticationService com.thinkbiganalytics.auth.AuthServiceAuthenticationProvider.authenticationService
```

Ah, no `authenticationService`. Why not?

```
Could not autowire field: com.thinkbiganalytics.datalake.podium.restclient.PodiumRestClient
```

Ah, no `PodiumRestClient`. Why not?

```
Could not autowire field: private boolean com.thinkbiganalytics.datalake.podium.restclient.PodiumRestClientImpl.useHttps
```

Okay, it couldn't create the `PodiumRestClientImpl` because it couldn't autowire the `boolean useHttps`. Why not?

```
Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'boolean'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid boolean value [${podium.useHttps}]
```

So it couldn't autowire `PodiumRestClientImpl.useHttps` because it couldn't convert the `String` with a value of `${podium.useHttps}` to a `boolean`. Fair enough.

So it seems that either you are not using SpEL correctly when autowiring a configuration value or you have not got a `PropertySource` configured to resolve placeholders to configuration values.

Comment: Thanks a Ton, Boris and appreciate the way to broke it down step by step.

Comment: Glad I could help @Des. If this answer solved your problem, then consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/214894).